# How to perform a segue from app delegate after sign in with google

Tags: ios, swift, segue, google-signin

i created a sign in with google feature, and everything is working with the signing in with the firebase and authentication. my problem is that after a successful sign in i want the app to move to a differnent page/controller from the app `delegate.`

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
                            let viewController: SigninViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoogleTabController") as! SigninViewController;

                            // Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
                            let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
                            rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
```

is giving me an error that reads "could not cast value of type uitabbarcontrller to signinViewcontroller"

here is my full code:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
          let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                            accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
      
       
        let number = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
        let numberString = String(number)
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let googleName = user.profile.name
        let googleEmail = user.profile.email
        let googleUsername = user.profile.name+numberString
        let country = ""
        let bio = ""
        let profImg = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 100)?.absoluteString
        let password = ""
        
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResulft, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error)
            }else{
                let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userid).getDocuments(){querySnapshot, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }else
                    {
                        if querySnapshot!.isEmpty{
                        db.collection("users").document(userid).setData([
                        "name": googleName!,
                        "username": googleUsername,
                        "email": googleEmail!,
                        "password": password,
                        "uid": userid,
                        "country": country,
                        "bio": bio,
                        "profileImage": profImg!,
                            ]) { err in
                            if err != nil {
                                           
                                            
                            } else {
                        print("logged in success and db stored")
                        //below code doesnt work
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
                        let viewController: SigninViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoogleTabController") as! SigninViewController;

                        // Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
                        let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
                        rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                        }else{
                        //here perform segue
                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
                            let viewController: SigninViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoogleTabController") as! SigninViewController;

                            // Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
                            let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
                            rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
              
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
let viewController: SigninViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoogleTabController") as! SigninViewController;
```

`GoogleTabController` is a tabViewController not `SigninViewController`  you need to use

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoogleTabController")!
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it fixed the error i was getting but now i am getting another error that reads "couldn't not cast value of type TransScreenViewController to UINavigationController", what is the problem? i am getting the error from this line ` let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController`

Comment: your root isn't a navigation controller it's `TransScreenViewController `  make sure to embed `TransScreenViewController ` inside a navigation

Comment: how would i do that, with code or from main.storyboard?

Comment: how, sorry i am not advanced in swift.